# How to maintain correct model binding behaviour when passing model property to partial view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views, model-binding, mvc-editor-templates

In ASP.NET MVC, I want to reuse a commonly used set of credit card fields by putting them in a partial view, and rendering that partial view inside another form in a parent view.

The issue is that if the CreditCard object is part of a model that is it's self a complex object, when I pass it through to the partial view, on form submission, the field names  are missing the parent property name prefix that would allow the default model binder to map the fields to the correct property of the complex object.

**Credit card fields rendered in partial view (Incorrect behaviour):**

```
@Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Pay/CCForm.cshtml", Model.CreditCard ,
 new ViewDataDictionary());
```

Posts string:

PayOption=1&CreditCardNumberPlainText=0000000000000&StartDateMm=03&StartDateYyyy=2008&ExpiryDateMm=03&ExpiryDateYyyy=2017&SecurityCode=111&IssueNumber=1&X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest

**Standard form (Correct behaviour) where credit card fields rendered in main view with fields such as:**

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.CreditCard.IssueNumber, new {@maxlength = 3, @size = 3})
```

Post string:

PayOption=1&CreditCardInfo.CreditCardNumberPlainText=0000000000000000&CreditCardInfo.StartDateMm=02&CreditCardInfo.StartDateYyyy=2009&CreditCardInfo.ExpiryDateMm=04&CreditCardInfo.ExpiryDateYyyy=2014&CreditCardInfo.SecurityCode=111&CreditCardInfo.IssueNumber=1&X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't make a EditorTemplate for this CreditCard class then just use it in your parent view

*E.G.*

EditorTemplate: `CreditCard.cshtml` in `EditorTemplates` folder in the `Shared` folder
add in this file the edit fields for CreditCard. Something like this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.IssueNumber)
//........... So on.
```

then in your view just call:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.CreditCard)
```

Comment: Thanks, love a simple answer. Had seen the EditorFor helper before but hadn't quite grasped the use case. Found a good guide here: http://coding-in.net/asp-net-mvc-3-how-to-use-editortemplates/

Comment: Wish I understood how that would create different form name attributes so binding would work on the server...